# Is IE 11 tr:active selector broken?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I can select and highlight td elements in IE but cannot highlight all td in a tr using tr:active.  This works as expected in FireFox and Chrome.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CoolBlue/ahhdbo60/) is a JsFiddle example, am I doing something wrong in the CSS?

Still doing it...
[image]
[image]
In Chrome, Safari, Opera and FF...
[image]
HTML

```
<body>
    <br />
    <div id="rowCount">
        <table class='t2'>
            <tr>
                <th>Click a Cell should highlight all in the row</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>tr:active td</td>
                <td>td:active</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
table {
    cursor: default;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: transparent;
}
div {
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    border:4px solid #CC3300;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #4D70DB;
}
th{
    text-align: left;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

tr:hover td {
    border:1px solid #CC3300;
}

tr:active td{
    background-color: #CC3300;
}
td:active {
    color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: Weird that `td:active` seems to work in IE 11, but not `tr:active td`.  Maybe something to do with how it bubbles to its parent?

Comment: Seems to be an old bug (https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781417/active-pseudo-selector-on-parent-elements) that they believed had been fixed. Evidently it is not. Just posted there to let them know.. The `:active` does not bubble in IE.

Comment: You could be running an old IE11 build?

Comment: @Antfish why, is it not happening for you?

Comment: No, just because @GabyakaG.Petrioli suggested it was an old bug and MS said they'd fixed it.

Comment: @Antfish when i posted the link i had tested it and it was valid (***it still is, so they should not have closed the bug***)

Comment: Cool Blue, your css is perfectly valid. I have seen this before, it's an IE issue and there is no known way of getting around it with just css.

Comment: you could use something like selectivizr (http://selectivizr.com/) which adds classes on for example active elements so you dont have to rely on that the pseudoselector is working.

Comment: For the future reader, this bug is still present in IE9-11 in 2018, your best bet is to fix it via JS (mousedown/mouseup events).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct, the `tr:active` is not working on IE11 and below. I have not tested on the Edge browser yet, but this is clearly a bug. It can be reproduced in IE9, 8, 7 as well.

After doing a bit of research, I found that most other browsers had this bug too before. See [that bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=305618) on Firefox (exactly the same problem).

I searched Microsoft Connect and did not find a bug report that was reporting exactly your problem. I created a new bug report that you can follow using [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1691431/tr-active-is-ignored-but-tr-hover-works).

Like some said in the comments of the topic post, another post on Microsoft Connect was also strongly related, you can [follow this bug report here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781417/active-pseudo-selector-on-parent-elements).

Thank you for pointing that out. It is a really good find.

PS: That is sadly the maximum I can do. Later today I will test on Edge to see if this problem is resolved on this new browser.

---

UPDATE

The Microsoft Edge Team contacted me to add:
"This issue appears to be fixed in MS Edge."